# How to fix incorrect fuzzy-matches with over 90 thresholds?

Tags: python, string-matching, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

I have two datasets that I need to fuzzy-match over a column which contains organization names. I used fuzzywuzzy library in Python and set the threshold 50 (see the code below). The code successfully matched some names. When I eyeballed the matches, I realized an issue. The issue is there are some matches with 90 threshold but two names are totally different.

For example, these following two names matched with 91:

**"PARIS HEALTH CORPORATION"** and **"LONDON HEALTCARE CORPORATION"**

(I replaced the first words with Paris and London for confidentially).

**I am wondering how to match these types of matches in a right way?**

Also two datasets have address and zip codes too but I haven't used address to match two datasets yet.

I got the code from [this page](https://medium.com/@rtjeannier/combining-data-sets-with-fuzzy-matching-17efcb510ab2).

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def match_name(name, list_names, min_score=0):
    max_score = -1
    max_name = ""
    for name2 in list_names:
    score = fuzz.ratio(name, name2)
    if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
        max_name = name2
        max_score = score
    return (max_name, max_score)

dict_list = []
for name in df.SYSNAME:
match = match_name(name, df1.PAYER_NAME, 50)
dict_ = {}
dict_.update({"SYSNAME" : name})
dict_.update({"match_name" : match[0]})
dict_.update({"score" : match[1]})
dict_list.append(dict_)
merge_table = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This matches at 91% due to the model built behind the *fuzzywuzzy* library.
I am guessing that the words you have changed instead of Paris and London even have letters in common.

In your example, I believe that you should:
1) split your corporations list based on the localization
2) run the model
3) append the results back together

This would avoid this issue if your corporations are not in multiple locations.

If they are, then you could strip the corporation names from common elements:

```
remove_words = ["healthcare", "corporations", "llc", "corp", "parnters"]
for i in remove_words:
    corp['corporation'] = corp['corporation'].str.replace(i, "", case = False)
```

This way, when you run your model, it would run it on words that matter to you.

I hope it helps.
BR.